# Controlling CSS based hover effects

Tags: css, hover

To my knowledge, the answer to this is no, can't be done, but I need a second opinion:

If I have the following:

```
<li>
    <a >#</a>
    <div class="sub">
    #
    </div>
</li>
```

and have a background image that appears on `li a:hover` is it possible to have that background stay on when hovering on the `.sub` div? This also has to work pure CSS - no javascript cheats.

My understanding is because `.sub` isn't a child of the `a` we can't reference it in css to keep the hover.

Because the image is for only one section of the code, I can't move it to the `li` and reference `li:hover a`.

Comment: Have you tried achieving it using `li:hover .sub`?

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/B7Au2/1/ Note, that won't work IE < 8.

Comment: And yes, you're right, you [can't select parents or traverse up and down in pure CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

Comment: as mentioned, i can't use `li:hover` for the background because of the funkiness with it (long story - i was hoping not to have to rework the whole thing - so much for that). I think Jared has answered it for me - can't be done. :) thanks guys

Comment: I didn't see that at the end of the sentence. Can you use a class on that `li`, or put the [`div` inside the `a`](http://jsfiddle.net/B7Au2/4/)?

Comment: I take it the desired behaviour is that hovering `.sub` doesn't cause the background image to appear if you entered it other than through tha `<a>` - otherwise, you could do `li a:hover, li .sub:hover`

Comment: If `a` and `.sub` are siblings, they can't affect each other. `.sub` would have to be a child of `a` to affect it with CSS.  Otherwise, you'll have to use JavaScript which should be pretty trivial.

Comment: @Fozzyuw--not true. `a` can affect `.sub` with the sibling selector `+`. Note the example for my answer below `a:hover + .sub`.

Comment: @Fozzyuw--however, in rereading his question, I think I understand better now that he wants a hover effect on `a` when `.sub` is hovered.

Comment: @Jared Farrish--you can traverse down (not up) by the adjacent sibling `+` selector or the general sibling `~` selectors.

Comment: @ScottS - Where did I say you can't traverse down?

Comment: @Jared Farrish--your second comment above: "can't select parents or traverse up and down in pure CSS."

Comment: @ScottS - "traverse **UP** then down" `<` What I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what all you are trying to achieve, but there are [many hover effects that can be done](http://jsfiddle.net/PaMTq/3/).

**SECOND UPDATE**: If you don't need to interact (other `a` tags, etc) at all with anything in the `div`, [then this way cheats to get the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/PaMTq/12/). Note how the anchor inside the `div` does not register because of the `z-index`.

**UPDATE** I think I understand your issue better now. Can you add a wrapper and [do the following](http://jsfiddle.net/PaMTq/6/)?:

### Example HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>  
      <a>Some anchor text</a>
      <div class="sub">Some div content <a>and anchor</a></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Example CSS:

```
li:hover {
    background-color: cyan;
}


li > div:hover > a {
    background-color: green;
}

a:hover {
    color: yellow;
    display: block;
}

a:hover + .sub {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.sub:hover {
    color: red;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: i've never seen the `+` in css before. i've seen `>` but don't understand it's use. I'm not even sure what those are called to try and research. you wouldn't happen to have a link that explains how those work? Thanks!

Comment: @Aninemity--can you explain further why you think you cannot use `li:hover a` (or some `li:hover`) for the effect you want. That just doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: @Aninemity--and glad I could make your day :-).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a `class` on the `li` or modify the `div.sub` to be in the `a`, you're probably out of luck without Javascript:

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

However, if you can, you could use:

```
<ul>
  <li class="sub">
      <a>Class #</a>
      <div class="sub">#</div>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a>Inner #
          <div class="sub">#</div>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a>None #</a>
      <div class="sub">#</div>
  </li>
</ul>

li.sub:hover,
li a:hover {
    background: url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG);
}
li a {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: block;
}
.sub {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B7Au2/4/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can modify the html, but if you can, try swapping the div and the a:

```
<li>
    <div class="sub">
    #
    </div>
    <a >#</a>
</li>
```

Now you can use the adjacent sibling selector:

```
li a:hover, li .sub:hover + a {background:url('some-image.png')}
```

Unfortunately there's no way to select the previous element through CSS: that's why you need to swap your elements.