# Unhide element when hovered over element

Tags: css, hover, element

Need little CSS help! I want to unhide a elements when another element is hovered.

For example:

```
<div class="Welcome"><a>Welcome to our site<a><div>
<div class="Message">Thanks for touching me!<div>
```

CSS

```css
.Message {
    display: hidden
}

.Welcome a: hover {
/*I want to make .Message visible now. Any ideas?*/
}
```

Comment: You should probably use JavaScript for this

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535105/controlling-css-based-hover-effects) might help. Yes, `.js` would be easiest and more functional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really the best you can get, when you hover over `.Welcome` `.Message` is displayed. This uses the adjacent sibling [`+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) selector.

```css
.Message {
    display: none;
}

.Welcome:hover + .Message {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/ZPVSU/

Comment: how is this as far as cross browser support?

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) chrome, ff, opera, safari, IE7+

Comment: Thanks, I found this for an additional ref... http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector although the browsers listed seem rather dated.

Comment: Hey, thisn't working. To get a better idea, i'm trying to do it with my site's featured area. Link: http://www.thetechnodaily.com

.recentpost-1 img:hover + .content-heading {
display:block;
}

.content-heading {
display: none;
}

Comment: @LavanyaArora use this `.recentpost-1 a:hover + .content-heading { display:block; } .content-heading { display: none; }` instead since `.content-heading` adjacent sibling is the `a`.

Comment: @LavanyaArora try refreshing your browser, cause I can see it working

Comment: Guys, do you know how to slow down this animation while opacity is changing?

Comment: @LavanyaArora what animation? Also you might want ask that in  new question. Also if an answer solves your problem you should accept it as the answer by clicking on the tick next to it

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy with a bit of jQuery.

**CSS**

```
​div.Message{
    display:none;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="Welcome">Welcome to our site<div>
<div class="Message">Thanks for touching me!<div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.Welcome').hover(
    function () {
    $('.Message').show();
  }, 
    function () {
    $('.Message').hide();
  }
);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gxn34/

**EDIT**

*To answer your question below*

You would need to add the following to your page, usually in the `<head>` section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.Welcome').hover(
            function () {
        $('.Message').show();
          }, 
            function () {
        $('.Message').hide();
          }
        );
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: Where do I insert this jQuery?

Comment: I also recommend jquery for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Welcome a: hover {
  display: block;
}
```